# Average of values based on distinct ID by Java Stream

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a class called Tag.

```
public class Tag {
    String tag_id;
    int x_pos;
    int y_pos;
    int z_pos;
    public String getTag_id() {
        return tag_id;
    }
    public void setTag_id(String tag_id) {
        this.tag_id = tag_id;
    }
    public int getX_pos() {
        return x_pos;
    }
    public void setX_pos(int x_pos) {
        this.x_pos = x_pos;
    }
    public int getY_pos() {
        return y_pos;
    }
    public void setY_pos(int y_pos) {
        this.y_pos = y_pos;
    }
    public int getZ_pos() {
        return z_pos;
    }
    public void setZ_pos(int z_pos) {
        this.z_pos = z_pos;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return this.tag_id +" "+this.x_pos+" "+this.y_pos+" "+this.z_pos;
    }


}
```

Now I have an array list of Tag.

```
ArrayList<Tag> tag_info = new ArrayList<>();
```

Tag id can be A, B, C or anything. It's dynamic, not fixed.
I need to get the average of x_pos, y_pos and z_pos of the `tag_info`. Size of array list is also dynamic, can range in between 60-70. I have written it all using loops, but wanted to convert it using Stream.

I extracted the unique IDs using :

```
Stream<Tag> a = tag_info.stream().filter(distinctByKey(Tag::getTag_id));
```

But now I don't want to run a loop over all value and get the average. Anything simpler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Collectors::averagingDouble`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#averagingDouble-java.util.function.ToDoubleFunction-)

```
    Double xAvg = tag_info.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.averagingDouble(Tag::getX_pos));
    Double yAvg = tag_info.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.averagingDouble(Tag::getY_pos));
    Double zAvg = tag_info.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.averagingDouble(Tag::getZ_pos));
```

Also if you want to get average values by each `tag_id` use `groupingBy`:

```
    Map<String, Double> map = tags.stream()
            .collect(groupingBy(Tag::getTag_id,
                    averagingDouble(Tag::getX_pos)));
```

Comment: I actually need the values by each tag. When I try the above code, it says `The method averagingDouble(Tag::getX_pos) is undefined for the type filterRows`.

Comment: @driftking9987 try add static import `import static java.util.stream.Collectors.averagingDouble;`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe caching total can help to avoid recalculating through all the values, like following:

- New class TagsList with `long total_x`, `long total_y`, `long total_z`
- when tag is added, removed from TagsList then total is modified appropriately
- Tag can be modified to accept ChangeEventListener (which is TagsList), when pos_x, pos_y or pos_z is modified then listeners are informed about that, so TagsList can update its total values
- getAverage_Pos_x is just total_x / numberOfTags